# Why Transactors have been deprecated in Akka 2.3

Tags: scala, akka, scala-2.10

On the Migration guide from Akka 2.2.x to 2.3 I noticed the following brief mention:

> Deprecated STM Support for Agents
>   Agents participating in enclosing STM transaction is a deprecated feature.

I googled to find out about the reasons for this choice and I could not find any discussion about it.

Why was this feature deprecated (and eventually will be removed) from Akka?
Is there a newer approach to the achieve similar results?

Akka Essentials, by Munish K. Gupta, dedicates a whole chapter to the topic so, being a recent adopter of Akka, I would be surprised if the feature was just dropped...

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason is that transactors won't make much sense in a clustered environment. Since akka tries to offer location transparency, this features has fallen out of favor.

Comment: Here is a line from transactor docs: "Might not be often but when you do need this then you are screwed without it". So I'm screwed? What are alternatives?